# How to write a generator class?

Tags: python, generator, fibonacci

I see lot of examples of generator functions, but I want to know how to write generators for classes. Lets say, I wanted to write Fibonacci series as a class.

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1

    def __next__(self):
        yield self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b

f = Fib()

for i in range(3):
    print(next(f))
```

Output:

```
<generator object __next__ at 0x000000000A3E4F68>
<generator object __next__ at 0x000000000A3E4F68>
<generator object __next__ at 0x000000000A3E4F68>
```

Why is the value `self.a` not getting printed?  Also, how do I write `unittest` for generators?

Comment: It's not easy to write generator class, especially for Python (If you mean by generator the generator -- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators)

Comment: If you mean implement iteratable protocol then it can be done (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and this is about what your code snippet is.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

> ## How to write a generator class?

You're almost there, writing an *Iterator* class (I show a Generator at the end of the answer), but `__next__` gets called every time you call the object with `next`, returning a generator object. Instead, to make your code work with the least changes, and the fewest lines of code, use `__iter__`, which makes your class instantiate an *iterable* (which isn't technically a *generator*):

```py
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            yield self.a
            self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b
```

When we pass an iterable to `iter()`, it gives us an *iterator*:

```
>>> f = iter(Fib())
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(next(f))
...
0
1
1
```

To make the class itself an *iterator*, it does require a `__next__`:

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1        
    def __next__(self):
        return_value = self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b
        return return_value
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

And now, since `iter` just returns the instance itself, we don't need to call it:

```
>>> f = Fib()
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(next(f))
...
0
1
1
```

> ### Why is the value self.a not getting printed?

Here's your original code with my comments:

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1
        
    def __next__(self):
        yield self.a          # yield makes .__next__() return a generator!
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b

f = Fib()

for i in range(3):
    print(next(f))
```

So every time you called `next(f)` you got the generator object that `__next__` returns:

```
<generator object __next__ at 0x000000000A3E4F68>
<generator object __next__ at 0x000000000A3E4F68>
<generator object __next__ at 0x000000000A3E4F68>
```

> ### Also, how do I write unittest for generators?

You still need to implement a send and throw method for a `Generator`

```
from collections.abc import Iterator, Generator
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Fib(self):
        f = Fib()
        self.assertEqual(next(f), 0)
        self.assertEqual(next(f), 1)
        self.assertEqual(next(f), 1)
        self.assertEqual(next(f), 2) #etc...
    def test_Fib_is_iterator(self):
        f = Fib()
        self.assertIsInstance(f, Iterator)
    def test_Fib_is_generator(self):
        f = Fib()
        self.assertIsInstance(f, Generator)
```

And now:

```
>>> unittest.main(exit=False)
..F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_Fib_is_generator (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in test_Fib_is_generator
AssertionError: <__main__.Fib object at 0x00000000031A6320> is not an instance of <class 'collections.abc.Generator'>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
<unittest.main.TestProgram object at 0x0000000002CAC780>
```

So let's implement a generator object, and leverage the `Generator` abstract base class from the collections module (see the source for its [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d5d3249e8a37936d32266fa06ac20017307a1f70/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L309)), which means we only need to implement `send` and `throw` - giving us `close`, `__iter__` (returns self), and `__next__` (same as `.send(None)`) for free (see the [Python data model on coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects)):

```
class Fib(Generator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1        
    def send(self, ignored_arg):
        return_value = self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b
        return return_value
    def throw(self, type=None, value=None, traceback=None):
        raise StopIteration
```

and using the same tests above:

```
>>> unittest.main(exit=False)
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.002s

OK
<unittest.main.TestProgram object at 0x00000000031F7CC0>
```

### Python 2

The ABC `Generator` is only in Python 3. To do this without `Generator`, we need to write at least `close`, `__iter__`, and `__next__` in addition to the methods we defined above.

```
class Fib(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1        
    def send(self, ignored_arg):
        return_value = self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b
        return return_value
    def throw(self, type=None, value=None, traceback=None):
        raise StopIteration
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return self.send(None)
    def close(self):
        """Raise GeneratorExit inside generator.
        """
        try:
            self.throw(GeneratorExit)
        except (GeneratorExit, StopIteration):
            pass
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("generator ignored GeneratorExit")
```

Note that I copied `close` directly from the Python 3 [standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/_collections_abc.py), without modification.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you so much for your response, this is exactly what I was looking for. What is the best way to learn more about iterators and generators ?

Comment: @Pritam I expand a lot on that subject in this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31042491/541136

Comment: @AaronHall In the second instantiation `f = iter(Fib())`, (after "And now:"), you probably meant to instantiate without wrapping the Fib class in the `iter` function?

Comment: @loxosceles The intention is to demonstrate the usage of the iterator protocol. An iterator has an `__iter__` method that, when called, returns itself. It might seem redundant, but it's what's called when the iterator object is placed in an iteration context (like a for loop or passed to an iterable constructor).

Comment: This answer is wrong, because it removes the generator and assumes `__next__()` can be implemented directly. Fibonacci was just an example, and not all algorithms should be refactored to avoid yield. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60229646/1440667.

Comment: @JaredDeckard I have clarified that the first section did not intend to give a *generator*, if that's what you're talking about. I also don't follow this: "Fibonacci was just an example, and not all algorithms should be refactored to avoid yield."

Comment: Your reply to "How to write a generator class?" only explains how to implement the iterator interface. Your response is organized incoherently. By the end you show how to copy the implementation for a coroutine from the cpython source code... That has nothing to do with implementing the generator interface in a class. Copying undocumented implementation code from cpython's source is bad practice, because it can break between minor releases. Not only that, but since it is not part of any PEP spec it may only work with cpython and break on other interpreters.

Answer (score 10):

`__next__` should *return* an item, not yield it.

You can either write the following, in which `Fib.__iter__` returns a suitable iterator:

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            yield self.a
            self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b

f = Fib(10)

for i in f:
    print i
```

or make each instance itself an iterator by defining `__next__`.

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        x = self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return x

f = Fib()

for i in range(10):
    print next(f)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you give the class an `__iter__()` method [implemented as a generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types), "it will automatically return an iterator object (technically, a generator object)" when called, so *that* object's `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods will be the ones used.

Here's what I mean:

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            value, self.a, self.b = self.a, self.b, self.a+self.b
            yield value

f = Fib()

for i, value in enumerate(f, 1):
    print(value)
    if i > 5:
        break
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
```

Comment: This makes it an iterable, not a generator

Comment: @Brian: Better?

Comment: Yes this makes it a proper generator class

Answer (score 4):

Using `yield` in a method makes that method a **generator**, and calling that method returns a **generator iterator**. `next()` expects a generator iterator which implements `__next__()` and `return`s an item. That is why `yield`ing in `__next__()` causes your generator class to output generator iterators when `next()` is called on it.

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator

When implementing an interface, you need to define methods and map them to your class implementation. In this case the `__next__()` method needs to call through to the generator iterator.

```py
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1
        self.generator_iterator = self.generator()

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.generator_iterator)

    def generator(self):
        while True:
            yield self.a
            self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b

f = Fib()

for i in range(3):
    print(next(f))
# 0
# 1
# 1
```

Comment: Citing the glossary is usually a good thing, but in this case I believe it is imprecise to the point of being incorrect. See my answer for my reasoning. Where the glossary is contradicted by the implementation, the implementation would be the correct source.

Comment: Differentiating "generator" and "generator iterator" is an important part of the answer to this question. The glossary is the most precise source available. The glossary does not contradict the implementation. You are conflating iterators and coroutines with generators, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `yield` in `__next__` function and implement `next` also for compatibility with python2.7+

**Code**

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1
    def __next__(self):
        a = self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b
        return a
    def next(self):
        return self.__next__()
```