# Could we implement generator using class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

when we look at the Python documentation we could see that generators are always defined using yield statement, but in the Internet we could see that some people are trying to implement generators using classes (eg. here [How to write a generator class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983569/how-to-write-a-generator-class)).

Here is example generator implementation using classes:

```
from collections import Generator
class Fib(Generator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1        
    def send(self, ignored_arg):
        return_value = self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a+self.b
        return return_value
    def throw(self, type=None, value=None, traceback=None):
        raise StopIteration
```

When we execute it in repl we can see it is not the generator, but ordinary object. It only tries to behave like generator.

```
>>> x = Fib()
>>> x
<__main__.Fib object at 0x7f05a61eab70>
```

When we look at PEP 342:

> 4. Add a close() method for generator-iterators, which raises GeneratorExit at the point where the generator was paused.

I think it is not possible to meet that condition using own implementation with classes.

Am I wrong? Is it really possible to implement real generator using classes?

Comment: It's not acting like a generator. You printed an object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object

Answer (score 3):

Generators are simply a type of *iterator*. From the [datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> Generator functions
>   A function or method which uses the `yield` statement [...] is called a generator function. Such a function, when called, **always returns an iterator object** which can be used to execute the body of the function: calling the iterator’s `iterator.__next__()` method will cause the function to execute until it provides a value using the `yield` statement. When the function executes a return statement or falls off the end, a `StopIteration` exception is raised and the iterator will have reached the end of the set of values to be returned.

You can't tell by the `repr()` output if something is a generator. Python looks for the [iterator methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), and you can implement your own `send` and `throw` methods on top of those, as you have done.

As such, your implementation *works as designed*, it is valid iterator:

```
>>> x = Fib()
>>> next(x)
0
>>> next(x)
1
```

Without the `collections.abc.Generator` base, you can also implement your own [`__iter__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__) (this *has* to return `self`), and a [`__next__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) that produces the next value when called or raises `StopIteration` when done.

The base `collections.abc.Generator` implementation defines the `__next__` method for you and supplies an `__iter__` method that simply calls `self.send(None)`.

Comment: The question is a using coroutine object

Comment: @cricket_007: no it is not.

Comment: @cricket_007: a coroutine is a specialised iterable, but the object definition in the question is no such object.

Comment: Ah, so read the documentation wrong?
  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects

Comment: @cricket_007: *Coroutines **also** have the methods listed below, which are **analogous to those of generators***.

Comment: @cricket_007: You didn't read the [section *before* that](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutines), the OP has no `__await__` method.

Comment: My bad. Just the linked question pointed at the coroutine data model

Comment: So, how we can meet that condition "3. Add a new throw() method for generator-iterators, which **raises an exception at the point where the generator was paused,**."?

Comment: @Adam: why do you need that? You don't actually have a generator here, you have an *iterator* with the same methods. There is no actual paused block of code with an exception handler. Just change the state of your object so that it'll no longer produce new values, or has changed what values are produced, or whatever behaviour the *consumers* of your object would need to see.

Comment: **You don't actually have a generator here, you have an iterator with the same methods** This is the point of my question. Could we say that class which has this same methods like generator is generator? That's why I gave the example - it has methods like generator (even behaves almost like generator), but it doesn't work like generator defined by PEPs (especially 342). So is it the generator or not?

Comment: Here we have generator methods and description of them https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-methods .  When I read PEPs I see that generator can be created only by generator-function, I can't find other ways to create generator. That's why I think that (formally) Fib is not generator, even when it derives from Generator ABC.

Comment: @Adam: that's a philosophical question. Is an object that has all the same methods as a list, really a list? Python *doesn't care*; as long as other code can use it *just like you can use a generator*, it's all fine. No, it's not a generator, but it walks and talks like one.

Comment: @Adam: the `collections.abc` objects have two functions: letting you create objects that walk and talk like those types, *and* testing if for those types. If your goal is to produce an object that can stand in for a generator, then using `collections.abc.Generator` as a base is a great way of doing that.