# How to implement a generator in a Linked List class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, generator

I am trying to implement a simple Linked List in Python, and sort of trying to use all the Python concepts that I learned in it. I am stuck in implementing a Generator for the class.

Code:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
    

def next(self):
    tempNode = self.head
    while tempNode:
        yield tempNode.data
        tempNode = tempNode.nextNode
    else:
        raise StopIteration
```

Usage:

```
list_gen = iter(list1)
print (next(list_gen))
print (next(list_gen))
```

Output:

> generator object next at 0x7ff885b63960
>
> generator object next at 0x7ff885b63960

Neither is it printing the data value of the node, nor is it maintaining the current state of the method [as evident from the addresses returned].

Where am I making the mistake? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I modified the code to:

```
def next(self):
    tempNode = self.head
    while tempNode:
        tempNode2 = tempNode
        tempNode = tempNode.nextNode
        return tempNode2.data
    else:
        raise StopIteration
```

Now, the node value is printed, but as mentioned earlier, the state is not preserved and the value of the first node is printed every time.

Comment: Have you seen this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42983747/5606265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance variable to maintain the iterator's state between calls to `next()`. Also, `__next__` is not a generator function, it merely returns the next element, so do *not* use `yield` there:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    # ...
    self.iter_node = None  # maintain state of iterator

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def next(self):
    if self.iter_node is None  # reset iterator to allow repeated iteration
        self.iter_node = self.head or 'XXX'  # dummy for to signal end
    if self.iter_node != 'XXX':
        rval = self.iter_node.data
        self.iter_node = self.iter_node.nextNode or 'XXX'
        return rval
    else:
        self.iter_node = None
        raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion helped! Solved the issue.