# Custom generator object for lazily flattening large datasource

Tags: python, iterator, generator, lazy-loading

I'm looking for the object oriented equivalent of this function:

```
def lazy_gen_func(path):
    for line in open(path): 
        for token in line.split():
            yield token
```

[Related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42983747/3026051) suggest the following approach:

```
class eager_gen_obj(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        f = open(path)
        self.text = [token for line in f for token in line.split()]
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            result = self.text[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index += 1
        return result
```

With the downside that the full source file has to be loaded in memory when __init__ is called.

How do I create a custom generator object to lazily flatten nested source data?

Comment: Re: your suggested edit: you can’t use `with` when creating the generator (it’ll close the file immediately), hence the suggestion at the end to not leave `f` up to GC. (The remaining changes were also intentional.)

Comment: see also my second suggested edit to address this. I tested the with statement and it did not misbehave.

Comment: Ah, you probably tested it with `readlines`. `readlines` is not lazy. (Suggested edits get merged, by the way – I only saw the last version.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a generator, either from the original function – `self._generator = lazy_gen_func(path)` – or from an equivalent generator expression:

```
class LazyGenObj:
    def __init__(self, path):
        f = open(path)
        self._generator = (token for line in f for token in line.split())

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self._generator)
```

It might also be a good idea to pass the file object to this instead of a path so the caller is free to close it explicitly.