# Generator and context manager at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, contextmanager

Imagine I have some code that I want it to run:

```
with F() as o:
    while True:
        a = o.send(2)
        print(a)
```

It means that the `F` class should return an `generator` and also it is `context manager`, generally I want a context manager to be generator too.

I tried this:

```
class F:

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print('exit')

    def __next__(self):
        return 5

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

As expected this will return `AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'send'`, I handled this error by adding:

```
def send(self, param):
    self.__next__()
```

but I think it is not a good way to do this, I look around and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983569/how-to-write-a-generator-class), but they are not using `send` as I want, I need that instance to be a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.abc` and subclass your class `F` from `Generator` ([manual pages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Generator)). If you implement **enter** and **exit**, your instance will be generator and have context manager support as well:

```
from collections.abc import Generator

class F(Generator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__my_generator = self._my_generator()
        next(self.__my_generator)   # prime the generator

    def _my_generator(self):
        while True:
            v = yield 42
            print('generator received ', v)

    # context manager interace:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print('exit')

    # Generator interface:
    def send(self, value):
        return self.__my_generator.send(value)

    def throw(self, typ, value=None, traceback=None):
        return self.__my_generator.throw(typ, value, traceback)


with F() as o:
    while True:
        a = o.send(2)
        print('I received ', a)
```

Prints:

```
generator received  2
I received  42
...etc.
```

Comment: This is surely better than my solution, thanks, the only question now is: the `o` can not be instance of generator? because I dont want to implement `send` on the class ?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar `collections.abc.Generator` will implement `close, __iter__, __next__` for you (if you provide `send` and `throw` methods). If you not subclass from `Generator`, you need to implement all those methods yourself.