# Using return (list) vs yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I've created two enumeration methods, one which returns a list and the other which returns a yield/generator:

```
def enum_list(sequence, start=0):
    lst = []
    num = start
    for sequence_item in sequence:
        lst.append((num, sequence_item))
        num += 1
    return lst


def enum_generator(sequence, start=0):
    num = start
    for sequence_item in sequence:
        yield (num, sequence_item)
        num += 1
```

A few questions on this:

(1) Is changing a list to a generator as simple as doing:

```
# build via list
l = list()
for item in items:
    l.append(item)

# build via iterator
# l = list() (1) <== delete this line
for item in items:
    yield item # (2) change l.append(...) to yield ...
```

(2) Is "lazy evaluation" the only reason to use a generator, or are there other reasons as well?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking here.What do you mean by "changing an array (do you mean list?) to a generator?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga updated the question.

Comment: Again, I'm not really sure what you are asking. Generators are a language construct that allow you to easily write iterators, in a way that is often easier to understand / more expressive than using the full iterator protocol. Lists and generators are two different things. Lists are containers, generators are iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) generator are simply created as adding **yield** to your iteration.

(2) Yes, for lazy evaluation. But generators are also used  to create stack and queue as they can be only iterate once. This property is also exploited in context manager, by **yielding** the context.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True thank you, I did the same mistake again, confounding iterator and generator.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not too sure why you say that. A generator class is a generator too, and with `__iter__` and `__next__` defined it does not need `yield` to be a generator. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983569/how-to-write-a-generator-class

Comment: @blhsing There is no such thing as "a generator class". A class can implement the *iterator protocol*, in which case, it can be a *iterator*. All generators are iterators, not all iterators are generators. If **it doesn't use yield then it is not a generator** (unless it is a generator expression). So try it yourself, with the example iterator in that linked answer, and `import types; print(isinstance(Fib(), types.GeneratorType))`

Comment: you cannot create "a generator from a class by using `__iter__` and `__next__`.

Comment: It's still not really correct. Normally, you wouldn't use `yield`, `__iter__` **and** `__next__` to create an iterator, rather, you would only use `__iter__` and `__next__` to create an iterator (**without yield** unless you want your iterator to return other iterators - generators, see the linked question in these comments). you *often* see an iterable class using a generator function to define `__iter__` because it doesn't require an additional, fulll *iterator* class definition, but that would be an *iterable*, not an *iterator*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just looked up the official glossary for generator. You're right indeed that the precise definition of a generator is a function that yields. I guess people simply mix up iterable classes with generators so much that they are practically used interchangeably, as evident by the many usages of the phrase "generator class" on SO without any correction until now. So thanks for pointing it out and clearing it up. :-)

Comment: @blhsing and, additionally, it is important to understand the distinction between an *iterable object* and an *iterator object*. another thing that is frequently misunderstood / glossed over. I swear I'm not just being a pedant, it is actually important. At the very least, it will make you look good in an interview :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, that's why I specifically said an iterable class, i.e. an object that defines `__iter__`, as opposed to an iterator class, i.e. an object that defines `__next__`, although they can be the same class.

Answer (score 0):

An additional difference in your case is that since list is created *before* use and generator is evaluated at each next call, the generator function can check the context and come to different result for each yield, depending on external conditions, which vary with time.

Consider pseudocode:

```
def alloted_time():
    while True:
         if len(global_queue)>10:
            yield 5
         else:
            yield 10
```

If queue is large, allot 5 mins for next person, else 10.

Comment: To make it a *useful* generator, you'd probably want a `while True:` around the whole thing. Otherwise, with only a single `yield` no matter which code path you exercise, this is basically just a function that's inconvenient to use.

Comment: @ShadowRanger of course! I felt I missed something, thanks.