# How to create a custom generator class that is correctly garbage collected

Tags: python, generator, python-internals

I'm trying to write a class in Python that behaves as a generator object, particularly in that when it's garbage collected `.close()` is called on it. That's important because it means that when the generator is interrupted I can make sure it'll clean up after itself, for example closing files or releasing locks.

Here's some explanatory code:
If you interupt a generator, then when it's garbage collected, Python calls `.close()` on the generator object, which throws a `GeneratorExit` error into the generator, which can be caught to allow cleanup, like follows:

```
from threading import Lock

lock = Lock()

def CustomGenerator(n, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    print("Generator Started: I grabbed a lock")
    try:
        for i in range(n):
            yield i
    except GeneratorExit:
        lock.release()
        print("Generator exited early: I let go of the lock")
        raise
    print("Generator finished successfully: I let go of the lock")

for i in CustomGenerator(100, lock):
    print("Received ", i)
    time.sleep(0.02)
    if i==3:
        break

if not lock.acquire(blocking=False):
    print("Oops: Finished, but lock wasn't released")
else:
    print("Finished: Lock was free")
    lock.release()
```

```
Generator Started: I grabbed a lock
Received  0
Received  1
Received  2
Received  3
Generator exited early: I let go of the lock
Finished: Lock was free
```

However, if you try to implement your own generator object by inheriting from `collections.abc.Generator`, Python doesn't seem to notice that it should call close when the object is collected:

```
from collections.abc import Generator
class CustomGeneratorClass(Generator):
    def __init__(self, n, lock):
        super().__init__()
        self.lock = lock
        self.lock.acquire()
        print("Generator Class Initialised: I grabbed a lock")
        self.n = n
        self.c = 0

    def send(self, arg):
        value = self.c
        if value >= self.n:
            raise StopIteration
        self.c += 1
        return value

    def throw(self, type, value=None, traceback=None):
        print("Exception Thrown in Generator: I let go of the lock")
        self.lock.release()
        raise StopIteration

for i in CustomGeneratorClass(100, lock):
    print("Received ", i)
    time.sleep(0.02)
    if i==3:
        break

if not lock.acquire(blocking=False):
    print("Oops: Finished, but lock wasn't released")
else:
    print("Finished: Lock was free")
    lock.release()
```

```
Generator Class Initialised: I grabbed a lock
Received  0
Received  1
Received  2
Received  3
Oops: Finished, but lock wasn't released
```

I thought that inheriting `Generator` would be sufficient to convince python that my CustomGeneratorClass was a generator and should have `.close()` called on it when garbage collected.

I assume this has something to do with the fact that while 'generator object' are some kind of special `Generator`:

```
from types import GeneratorType

c_gen = CustomGenerator(100)
c_gen_class = CustomGeneratorClass(100)

print("CustomGenerator is a Generator:", isinstance(c_gen, Generator))
print("CustomGenerator is a GeneratorType:",isinstance(c_gen, GeneratorType))

print("CustomGeneratorClass is a Generator:",isinstance(c_gen_class, Generator))
print("CustomGeneratorClass is a GeneratorType:",isinstance(c_gen_class, GeneratorType))
```

```
CustomGenerator is a Generator: True
CustomGenerator is a GeneratorType: True
CustomGeneratorClass is a Generator: True
CustomGeneratorClass is a GeneratorType: False
```

Can I make a user defined class object that is `GeneratorType`?

Is there something I don't understand about how python decides what to call `.close()` on?

How can I ensure that `.close()` is called on my custom generator?

---

This question is not a duplicate of [How to write a generator class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983569/how-to-write-a-generator-class). 
For actually making a generator class, the accepted answer for that question does recommends exactly the structure I'm trying here, which is a generator class but is not correctly garbage collected, as shown in the code above.

Comment: Hi @MattMcEwen. Did you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983569/how-to-write-a-generator-class)? I didn't read your question in details yet but I see that you're missing the dunder `__next__` to create a generator. Take a look the link.

Comment: inheriting from `Generator` gives you a `__next__()` which just calls `send(None)`. You can see this working above; when the custom generator class is iterated over before it breaks it works just like any other iterator, and gives back 0,1,2,3 in sequence

Comment: @Raphael `__next__` does not make something a generator, really. It makes an iterator, and in any case, the OP is using the abstract base class which already provides `__next__`

Comment: True, I oversimplified my 'answer'. Anyway, the purpose was to send the guy to the link :-). I didn't even see that he `import Generator`. Hope you find the solution @MattMcEwen. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PEP342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#id12), states:

> `[generator].__del__()` is a wrapper for `[generator].close()`. This will be called when the generator object is garbage-collected ...

The Generator class in [collections.abc](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/85e415108226cc5f3fdddd70196fc4c2a1d0f7f4/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L309) does not implement `__del__`, and neither do its superclasses or metaclass.

Adding this implementation of `__del__` to the class in the question results in the lock being freed:

```
class CustomGeneratorClass(Generator):

    ...

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()
```

Output:

```
Generator Class Initialised: I grabbed a lock
Recieved  0
Recieved  1
Recieved  2
Recieved  3
Exception Thrown in Generator: I let go of the lock
Finished: Lock was free
```

**Caveat:**

I'm not experienced with the intricacies of object finalisation in Python, so this suggestion should be examined critically, and tested to destruction.  In particular, the warnings about `__del__` in the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=generatorexit#object.__del__) should be considered.

---

A higher-level solution would be to run the generator in a context manager

```
with contextlib.closing(CustomGeneratorClass(100, lock)):
    # do stuff
```

but this is cumbersome, and relies on users of the code remembering to do it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Is there a reason this __del__ isn't defined in the generic type?

Comment: Not that I know of - at a guess, `__del__` can be problematic, as described in the language reference, so it's left to programmers to to decide whether or not they want to implement it.