# The Python Generator abstract base class doesn't implement the necessary __del__, is this intentional?

Tags: python, generator, abstract-base-class

Generator objects in Python are required to have a `close` method that exists to ensure that context managers are exited and `try...finally:` blocks are run before the object is garbage collected.

[PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342) defines the methods `send`,`throw`,`close` and `__del__` that generators must implement. Specifically, it states:

> `g.__del__()` is a wrapper for `g.close()`. This will be called when the
>   generator object is garbage-collected (in CPython, this is when its
>   reference count goes to zero).

The abstract type for Generator is in [collections.abc](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/_collections_abc.py)

```py
class Generator(Iterator):

    __slots__ = ()

    def __next__(self):
        """Return the next item from the generator.
        When exhausted, raise StopIteration.
        """
        return self.send(None)

    @abstractmethod
    def send(self, value):
        """Send a value into the generator.
        Return next yielded value or raise StopIteration.
        """
        raise StopIteration

    @abstractmethod
    def throw(self, typ, val=None, tb=None):
        """Raise an exception in the generator.
        Return next yielded value or raise StopIteration.
        """
        if val is None:
            if tb is None:
                raise typ
            val = typ()
        if tb is not None:
            val = val.with_traceback(tb)
        raise val

    def close(self):
        """Raise GeneratorExit inside generator.
        """
        try:
            self.throw(GeneratorExit)
        except (GeneratorExit, StopIteration):
            pass
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("generator ignored GeneratorExit")

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Generator:
            return _check_methods(C, '__iter__', '__next__',
                                  'send', 'throw', 'close')
        return NotImplemented
```

This abstract type enforces that `send`, `throw`,  and `close` are implemented in subclasses, but doesn't implement `__del__` either abstractly or concretely, or enforce that it's implemented. Its metaclasses don't either.

Naively, producing a subclass that doesn't manually define a `__del__` which wraps `close` gives Generators which are not correctly cleaned up after. The garbage collector only calls `__del__`, so if `__del__` doesn't exist, `close` is not called.

Is this intentional?

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775283/how-to-create-a-custom-generator-class-that-is-correctly-garbage-collected), [snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) pointed out to me that `__del__` can be fraught to implement, as indicated by the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=generatorexit#object.__del__), but I can't understand why that wouldn't also apply to the correct implementation of `__del__` as a wrapper for `close` in Python's native generator objects.

Comment: FWIW, the Generator abc implmentation is documented [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue24018), but it doesn't mention `__del__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be intentional. In an [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue38911) on the python bugtracker discussing this, Guido said that

> The presence of a `__del__` method can cause subtle behavior changes to
>   the GC, so I worry that adding `__del__` to that class now is going to
>   break currently-working code.
>
> Let's not destabilize the Generator class.