# Explicitly delete variables within a function if the function raised an error

Tags: python, namespaces, pytest, decorator

A particular problem with unit tests. Many of my test function have the following structure:

```
def test_xxx():
    try:
        # do-something
        variable1 = ...
        variable2 = ...
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
    finally:
        try:
            del variable1
        except Exception:
            pass
        try:
            del variable2
        except Exception:
            pass
```

And that structure is obviously not very nice. I could simplify the `finally` statement with:

```
finally:
    for variable in ("variable1", "variable2"):
        if variable in locals():
            del locals()[variable]
```

but it's still not that great. Instead, I would like to use a decorator `del_variables` to handle the `try` / `except` / `finally`.

Attempt, not working:

```
def del_variables(*variables):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as error:
                raise error
            finally:
                for variable in variables:
                    if variable in locals():
                        del locals()[variable]
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@del_variables("c")
def foo(a, b):
    c = 3
    return a + b + c
```

Since `locals()` doesn't refer to the namespace inside the execution of `function`. If I use `vars()`, I don't know what argument I should provide since that namespace as far as Python is concerned is already GC. Any idea how I could get that decorator to work, i.e. how I could explicitly delete variables from the namespace of `function`?

---

Notes: yes, this is a weird case where I need to explicitly call `del` because I overwrote the `__del__` methods of certain objects (stored in the variables I want to delete) to call c++ functions to destroy the c++ objects and references attached. And no, pytest fixtures are not a good solution in that case ;)

Comment: You don't need to delete local variables, they all go away when you leave the scope of the function.

Comment: @Barmar Read the Note section. This is an edge-case where I do need to explicitly call the `del` methods or some C++ attached objects are not destroyed and even if the python reference is removed, the C++ attached object remains and messes up the other tests (ruining even the test isolation..).

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a decorator. A decorater wraps around a function, but you need something that runs within the function.

Comment: I still don't think you need to use `del`. The `__del__` method runs when the object is garbage-collected. The `del` statement forces that to happen immediately (if the variable is the only reference to the object), but the same thing happens when the function exits.

Comment: @Barmar Sadly, explicitly deleting works while letting it to be done at the function "closure" fails. So there is merit in this ugly `del` statement. I'm wondering You say "A decorater wraps around a function, but you need something that runs within the function" and I completely agree. I'm looking now into a way to execute this function with a given namespace, or to create the namespace and give a ref to that namespace to the function in order to keep it alive after execution. Any idea?

Comment: Deleting from `locals()` doesn't actually delete the variable, and doesn't call the `__del__` method.

Comment: @Barmar Great. So that decorator would just never work :sigh:

Comment: Maybe a simpler decorator with a `gc.collect()` to force the collection might help..

Comment: `gc.collect()` is only needed for collecting cyclical data that has become garbage. Python uses reference counting, so objects with a single reference are collected immediately when that reference goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider restructuring your code. Relying on finalizers is not a good idea to begin with (see e.g. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63798053)). There are better mechanisms available for resource cleanup like context managers and/or pytest fixtures.

That being said:

If a test fails, pytest retains the raised exception. That exception contains all stack frames. The stack frame of the test function contains references to all objects created in the test.

With your current solution, you only delete the references in the test function. However, there may be more references to the objects in other stack frames. For example:

```
def func(some_obj):
    raise Exception

def test_test():
    obj = MyObj()
    func(obj)
```

`del obj` won't cause the object to be garbage collected, because now `func`'s stack frame still contains a reference to the object.

Since you cannot reasonably trace the references to your object through the call stack (it may be contained in dicts inside other objects etc.), I see no simple way to only delete selected objects like you requested. However, assuming that there are no global or cyclic references to the objects, you can simply delete all locals from the subsequent frames. Oh, and we're only talking about CPython, of course.

This can be achieved in multiple ways, but since you wanted a decorator:

```
import ctypes
import sys

def delete_locals(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            if tb:
                while tb.tb_next:
                    tb = tb.tb_next
                    tb.tb_frame.f_locals.clear()
                    ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(
                        ctypes.py_object(tb.tb_frame), ctypes.c_int(1)
                    )  # reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34671307

    return wrapper
```

Keep in mind that pytest now also has no chance to tell you the values of locals in its output.

Comment: Thank you, I learned something on pytest with this answer :)