# why is a generator function sometimes called not a generator?

Tags: python-3.x, generator

For the same object definition in the same program I get `TypeError: 'G' object is not iterable` in one place and not in another. I am wondering why and if there is a workaround?

```
class G: # generator class
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 1

    def __next__(self):
        yield self.c

g = G()
for i in range(3):
    print(next(g))
g = G()
i = 0
for x in g:
    print(x)
    i += 1
    if i >= 3:
        break
```

In the first for loop it works but in the second for loop I get the runtime error message `TypeError: 'G' object is not iterable`

The exact output is here:

```
<generator object G.__next__ at 0x000001ECA83E43C0>
<generator object G.__next__ at 0x000001ECA83E43C0>
<generator object G.__next__ at 0x000001ECA83E43C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\15104\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/15104/Dropbox/Programming/Python/try_tesserOCR/try1/try_with1.py", line 16, in <module>
    for x in g:
TypeError: 'G' object is not iterable
```

Although in this simple example one might say "why would anybody do that", this is because it is taken out of a longer program. Taking out the second `g = G()` doesn't change the behavior.

The only difference I see in the code is that the first loop calls the `next()` function explicitly and the second one calls it implicitly through the for x in g: statement. However it seems like "for" is perfectly valid way to use an iterable.

Comment: `for` is an iteration, which requires `__iter__` to be defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a generator class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983569/how-to-write-a-generator-class)

Comment: @norok2 thanks. I will read up on the difference.